# Why new and old value print When Pl/Sql program run.?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I run the following output come.
DECLARE
            inputData VARCHAR2(1024);
    BEGIN
            inputData :='&&inputData' ;
            Dbms_Output.put_line('Value entered is:' || inputData);
    END;
    /

```
Enter value for inputdata: check
old   4:         inputData :='&&inputData' ;
new   4:         inputData :='check' ;
Value entered is:check

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

But i Want to know the reason why old and new value print.I know How to off it.
i just want to know reason.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set verify off` to switch off the new and old value display. Hope this below snippet helps.

```
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF;
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    inputData VARCHAR2(1024);
  3  BEGIN
  4    inputData :='&&inputData' ;
  5    Dbms_Output.put_line('Value entered is:' || inputData);
  6  END;
  7  /
Enter value for inputdata: test
Value entered is:test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I know set verify off.but i want know reason why old and new value display.

Comment: Because that's exactly what the `verify` feature is for! It allows you to verify that the string substitution has been done correctly. If you don't want it, turn it off.